# Catch Popup n new form with Geckofx 45 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, c#-3.0, geckofx

i want to know how to catch a popup window in new form2 with Geckofx 45.

i was using webbrowser and it worked fine using the bellow code.

But now i want to make it work with Geckofx.

```
        SHDocVw.WebBrowser nativeBrowser;
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        nativeBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
        nativeBrowser.NewWindow2 += nativeBrowser_NewWindow2;

    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        nativeBrowser.NewWindow2 -= nativeBrowser_NewWindow2;
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }

    void nativeBrowser_NewWindow2(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        var popup = new Form2();
        popup.Owner = this;
        popup.Show(this);
        //popup.Hide();
        //popup.Visible = false;
        ppDisp = popup.Browser.ActiveXInstance;
    }
```

this worked for me with webbrowser controler.
Please i need help.

Best regards.